# How to append json object to the html table through ajax ( response is not iterable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to store data into my Html table from a JSON object. When I consol log data in my Impl class, data is print in my consol. but I'm not able to get data into the table.

My JSON Object -

```
    {
        "vehicleRegID":"V001",
        "vehicleMainBrand":"Lambogini",
        "vehicleSubBrand":"A1",
        "vehicleType": "Luxry",
        "vehicleNumberOfPassage":"6",
        "vehicleTransmissionType":"Auto",
        "vehicleFuelType":"Desel",
        "vehicleColor":"Black",
        "vehicleDailyRate":"400",
        "vehicleMonthlyRate":"500",
        "vehicleFreeMiles":"2",
        "vehicleExtraKmPrice":"8000"
     }
```

This is my HTML table and my ajax part -

```js
$("#test").click(function() {
  $("#vehicleTBody").empty();
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/Back_end_war_exploded/vehicle',
    async: true,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response); //object
      for (var i of response) {
        let row = `<tr><td>${i.vehicleSubBrand}</td><td>${i.vehicleRegID}</td><td>${i.vehicleSubBrand}</td><td>${i.vehicleDailyRate}</td><td>${i.vehicleMonthlyRate}</td><td>${i.vehicleFreeMiles}</td><td>${i.vehicleExtraKmPrice}</td></tr>`;
        $("#vehicleTBody").append(row);
      }

    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Vehicle</th>
      <th>Vehicle No:</th>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>DailyRate</th>
      <th>MonthlyRate</th>
      <th>FreeMiles</th>
      <th>ExtraKmPrice</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="vehicleTBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I run Thin I got Error Like This -

```
User.html?_ijt=ieo1ihg4uhcsvcrj4q1vqg1p4g:877 Uncaught TypeError: response is not iterable
    at Object.success (User.html?_ijt=ieo1ihg4uhcsvcrj4q1vqg1p4g:877)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found a Solution to my Own question. Only I had to do just assign a response.data into a variable...

```
   console.log(response);//object
                let array = response.data;
```